# Unable to find a version for the package "libc6"

Tags: package-management, versions, rstudio

After installing the newest Ubuntu version (22.04) Rstudio is not working any more. I found online, that installing an earlier libc6 version is supposed to help. I tried with
`sudo aptitude install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2` but it gives the error message:

```
Unable to find a version "2.31-0ubuntu9.2" for the package "libc6"
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
```

Does anyone know where I can find the version needed?

Thanks

Comment: Version 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is from two years ago. It was used in 20.04...but has since been superseded several times. The current version in 20.04 is 2.31-0ubuntu9.7. However, downgrading libc6 --a key package that many other packages depend upon-- is not recommended; it might break your system.

Comment: Try to compile RStudio, sources are available (for free version).

Comment: Changing versions of `libc6` will affect, probably break, nearly every program on your system (every program that uses `libc6`). Fix RStudio.