# Unable to find a version "2.31-0ubuntu9.2" for libc6-bin

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

While following [this answer,](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372227) I ran into this issue:

```
Unable to find a version "2.31-0ubuntu9.2" for the package "libc-bin"
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
```

After running this command:

```
sudo aptitude install libc-bin=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6:amd64=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6:i386=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6-dbg:amd64=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 locales=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

Do I need to add a new repository to get these old versions? Can I install different versions and still get the same effect?

Similar question: [Unable to find a version for the package "libc6"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406146/unable-to-find-a-version-for-the-package-libc6)

UPDATE:
I am running this in a Ubuntu 20.04 docker container in a [gitpod.io](https://www.gitpod.io) workspace.
I also found [this](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Biarch_Wine_On_Ubuntu) and I thought it might be an alternative solution to my problem, but I am not sure at all... Any ideas?

UPDATE AGAIN:
I can find `2.31-0ubuntu9.2` [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/i386/libc-bin/2.31-0ubuntu9.2) can I directly install the binary?

Comment: Please carefully read and understand the comments min your linked question.

Comment: I see `2.31-0ubuntu9.7` available; though it'll be replaced by `2.31-0ubuntu9.9` soon, but you've not provided any OS/release details.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I did, I am using a docker container so I don't care about messing up my system

Comment: @guiverc Will edit

Comment: I would be very careful trying to install older obsolete binary versions.  Installing one piece by hand will likely affect *all* other compiler bits.  Why do you need that specific version, instead of just installing `libc6>=2.3.1-0` and accepting latest compiler versions in the repos with security patches or bug fixes?

Comment: @ThomasWard I am trying to downgrade libc6 to version `9.2` because I was following the link listed at the top of my question. https://askubuntu.com/a/1372227/1592304